# LAN-intern solution for server-side auto-IP-block

Tags: ip, connections, ip-blocking

We got the problem, that our web server provider blocks our static IP address automatically, when we reach 200 simultaneous connections in the time window of 300 seconds. I'm running an Ubuntu server with an eBox on it, which could work as a gateway for limiting the connections. 
Which is the easiest solution? Ty.

Edit: A queue would be the best solution for all connections>200.

Comment: Sorry, what is blocking things?

Comment: Uhh get a new hosting provider that doesn't throttle your connections?

Comment: There's a few possibilities available, depending upon what behaviour you want. If I'm the 201st connection in any given 300 seconds, what do you expect me to see? An error, a timeout, a long pause, or something else?

Comment: A queue would be the best solution.

Comment: 200 connections is a fair bit to one server, can your provider not whitelist your IP? whats generating so many connections?

Comment: I'm with @Zypher on this one. I've never heard of a crazy limit like that on any business grade connection. If you're on a residential connection, you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @anthonysomerset: 200 connections is trivial on any decently popular web server.  I'd run far, far away from a host that started blocking connections after 200.

Comment: the provider doesn't offer whitelisting (we would have to upgrade). we are not on a residential connection (foreign country).

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access to your web server then run a SSH tunnel between your site and the remote site and connect through that. An example on how to do this can be found [here](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)

Everything then 'appears' as 1 connection (except for your web-server, although the connection limiting is likely not done on your web-server itself and even if it is `localhost` (which is where the connection will appear to be from) is normally whitelisted)

Answer (score 0):

Obvious thing to do here:

Call your provider, explain the problem and ask them to whitelist your IP

The other suggestion that explains tunneling all traffic trough ssh would work...
But the machine that is doing the tunneling must have a really good connection in your network and be somewhat powerfull since it will be encrypting! every single thing that goes trough...

(Assuming here that these 200 connections are coming from the employees? inside the office)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Our provider offers a whitelisting service but only for an upgrade. The thing with the power of the "tunneler" is a good point. Yes, the 200 connections are coming from the employers (which are maybe 20 which is strange anyway).